# Clone div and insertBefore

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to clone the div "questbox" and insert it over the existing div with new content. But the clones get repeated more than ones and in the wrong order. I want it in the order newest -> oldest.

HTML

```
<div id="top_quest">
    <div class="questbox">
        <div class="quest" style="display:inline-block; width:75%;">
            <h5 id="question"></h5>
        </div>
        <div class="up-vote" style="display:inline-block; float:right; width:25%; text-align:center;">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary knapp"><div class="arrow-up"/></button>
            <h5 id="upvotes"></h5>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function insertPost(){
    var obj, dbParam, xmlhttp, myObj, x;
    obj = { "table":"text", "limit":15 };
    dbParam = JSON.stringify(obj);
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

          for (x in myObj) {
              document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = myObj[x].text;
              document.getElementById("upvotes").innerHTML = myObj[x].upvotes;

              var parrent = document.getElementById("top_quest")
              var div = document.getElementById("top_quest");
              var clone = div.cloneNode(true);
              parrent.insertBefore(clone, parrent.firstChild);
          }
      }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "getPostsForLecture.php?q=", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: You're inserting clones of `#top_quest` **into** `#top_quest`. Naturally that's going to cause duplication. (You're also creating a **bunch** of elements with the `id`s `"top_quest"`, `"question"`, `"upvotes"`...which is invalid. There can be only one.)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems there:

1. You're inserting clones of `#top_quest` **into** `#top_quest`. Naturally that's going to cause duplication.
2. You're also creating a **bunch** of elements with the `id`s `"top_quest"`, `"question"`, `"upvotes"`...which is invalid. There can be only one.

So first, let's get rid of the `id` values on the question and upvotes elements, using classes instead:

```
<div id="top_quest">
    <div class="questbox">
        <div class="quest" style="display:inline-block; width:75%;">
            <h5 class="question"></h5>
        </div>
        <div class="up-vote" style="display:inline-block; float:right; width:25%; text-align:center;">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary knapp"><div class="arrow-up"/></button>
            <h5 class="upvotes"></h5>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, let's only copy the first `.questbox` inside `#top_quest`, instead of `#top_quest` itself. Along the way we'll look for the questions and upvotes elements differently (now they use classes) and a couple of other tweaks. See comments:

```
function insertPost(){
    var obj, dbParam, xmlhttp, top_quest;
    // *** Grab the parent element just once, no need to keep looking it up in the loop
    top_quest = document.getElementById("top_quest");
    obj = { "table":"text", "limit":15 };
    dbParam = JSON.stringify(obj);
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
          Object.keys(myObj).forEach(function(key) {
              var entry = myObj[key];
              // Get the first .questbox and clone it
              var clone = top_quest.querySelector(".questbox").cloneNode(true);
              // Set the question and upvotes
              clone.querySelector(".question").innerHTML = entry.text;
              clone.querySelector(".upvotes").innerHTML = entry.upvotes;
              // Append the clone at the top
              top_quest.insertBefore(clone, top_quest.firstChild);
          });
      }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "getPostsForLecture.php?q=", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Live example with fake ajax responses:

```js
var counter = 0;
function insertPost(){
    var obj, dbParam, xmlhttp, top_quest;
    // *** Grab the parent element just once, no need to keep looking it up in the loop
    top_quest = document.getElementById("top_quest");
    obj = { "table":"text", "limit":15 };
    dbParam = JSON.stringify(obj);
    // setTimeout to fake the ajax
    setTimeout(function() {
          // This really should be an array, not an object
          var myObj = {
             13: {text: "Question " + (++counter), upvotes: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)},
             14: {text: "Question " + (++counter), upvotes: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)},
             15: {text: "Question " + (++counter), upvotes: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)}
          };
          Object.keys(myObj).forEach(function(key) {
              var entry = myObj[key];
              // Get the first .questbox and clone it
              var clone = top_quest.querySelector(".questbox").cloneNode(true);
              // Set the question and upvotes
              clone.querySelector(".question").innerHTML = entry.text;
              clone.querySelector(".upvotes").innerHTML = entry.upvotes;
              // Append the clone at the top
              top_quest.insertBefore(clone, top_quest.firstChild);
          });
          if (counter < 10) {
              insertPost();
          }
    }, 500);
}
insertPost();
```

```html
<div id="top_quest">
    <div class="questbox">
        <div class="quest" style="display:inline-block; width:75%;">
            <h5 class="question"></h5>
        </div>
        <div class="up-vote" style="display:inline-block; float:right; width:25%; text-align:center;">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary knapp"><div class="arrow-up"/></button>
            <h5 class="upvotes"></h5>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Note: This always leaves that blank `.questbox`, though. You might consider using the `template` element, or pulling that first default one out of the DOM on page load and keeping a copy of it:

```js
// Grab the structure we'll clone when necessary
var questbox = document.querySelector("#top_quest .questbox");
questbox.parentNode.removeChild(questbox);
var counter = 0;
function insertPost(){
    var obj, dbParam, xmlhttp, top_quest;
    // *** Grab the parent element just once, no need to keep looking it up in the loop
    top_quest = document.getElementById("top_quest");
    obj = { "table":"text", "limit":15 };
    dbParam = JSON.stringify(obj);
    // setTimeout to fake the ajax
    setTimeout(function() {
          // This really should be an array, not an object
          var myObj = {
             13: {text: "Question " + (++counter), upvotes: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)},
             14: {text: "Question " + (++counter), upvotes: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)},
             15: {text: "Question " + (++counter), upvotes: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)}
          };
          Object.keys(myObj).forEach(function(key) {
              var entry = myObj[key];
              // Get the first .questbox and clone it
              var clone = questbox.cloneNode(true);
              // Set the question and upvotes
              clone.querySelector(".question").innerHTML = entry.text;
              clone.querySelector(".upvotes").innerHTML = entry.upvotes;
              // Append the clone at the top
              top_quest.insertBefore(clone, top_quest.firstChild);
          });
          if (counter < 10) {
              insertPost();
          }
    }, 500);
}
insertPost();
```

```html
<div id="top_quest">
    <div class="questbox">
        <div class="quest" style="display:inline-block; width:75%;">
            <h5 class="question"></h5>
        </div>
        <div class="up-vote" style="display:inline-block; float:right; width:25%; text-align:center;">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary knapp"><div class="arrow-up"/></button>
            <h5 class="upvotes"></h5>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I get: Uncaught TypeError: myObj.forEach is not a function
    at XMLHttpRequest.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange

Comment: @Frid: What does `myObj` look like? I assumed it was an array, but apparently not...?

Comment: Object {13: Object, 14: Object, 16: Object, 17: Object}
13
:
Object
ID
:
"13"
lecture_ID
:
"0"
posted_by_ID
:
null
text
:
"Hvorfor heter det capybara?"
time_posted
:
"2017-04-06 17:28:30"
upvotes
:
"0"

Comment: @Frid: It's an object rather than an array. I've updated the answer, but you might want to look at making it an array instead (by chaning the PHP). I can't see any reason it should be an object.

Comment: Okey, I will try changing it into an array! Thank you!

Comment: @Frid: But meanwhile, as I said, I've updated the answer to handle using your object instead.

Comment: Still can't get it to work :/  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null

Comment: @Frid: Don't know what to tell you, the example above works. You'll have to use the debugger to find out what part of the above you haven't incorporated into your code correctly. Good luck!